# Deploy AWS Lambda function without source code being visible

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there a way to deploy an AWS lambda function in such a way that the code is not readable or at least not editable directly from the AWS console.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the GUI Editor, just make sure the package size is larger than 3 MB.
Aside from that, deny the API call to update a Lambda Function for your GUI users and only grant that permission to the Pipeline.